# LiveData in view model not being set and is null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have the following `ViewModel`

```
class MainViewModel  @Inject constructor(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel(){
    private var _user: LoggedInUser? = null

    val allProjects: MutableLiveData<Array<Project>> = MutableLiveData()


    fun setUser(loggedInUser: LoggedInUser){
        _user = loggedInUser
        getAllProjects()
    }

    fun getAllProjects(): LiveData<Array<Project>> {
        println("MVM: In get all projects")
        allProjects.value = mainRepository.getAllProjects(_user!!.token).value
        println(" AFTER ${Arrays.toString(allProjects.value)}")
        return mainRepository.getAllProjects(_user!!.token)
    }
}
```

When I call `setUser()` or `getAllProjects()` the data does not get set. And in the **After** print statement I get null.

`MainRepository`:

```
@Singleton
class MainRepository {
    var job: CompletableJob? = null

    fun getAllProjects(auth: String): LiveData<Array<Project>> {
        println("REPO: In get all projects")
        val data = MutableLiveData<Array<Project>>()
        var job = Job()
        job?.let {theJob ->
            CoroutineScope(context = Dispatchers.IO + theJob).launch {
                val projects = RetrofitBuilder.apiService.getAllProjects("Bearer " + auth)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    data.value = projects
                    println("INSIDE: ${Arrays.toString(projects)}")
                    theJob.complete()
                }
            }
            println("getAllProjects DATA: ${Arrays.toString(data.value)}")
            return data
        }
    }

    fun cancelJobs(){
        job?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Here the *INSIDE* print statement prints out the data, while the `getAllProjects DATA` prints null. In my activity I both have an observer that is trigger when the LiveData is changed and that also prints out null (I did this to debug without worrying of async calls) and I also have button that prints out the live data -- that is also null.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: did you try to log? you are getting null from where? repository or viewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Use postValue. My guess is that you are using setValue not in main thread

Comment: I used post value in both the repository and the viewmodel and I still have the same behavior.